# Android <shape> resource - make auto mirrored

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

I need  XML resource auto mirrored. Unfortunately autoMirrored parameter is available for  only. Any idea how to overcome this without providing a separate drawable file in drawable-ldrtl folder?